# How to link a table to a detail view in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a table in Angular which takes data from a web api and its populated with it. What I want to do is link the first column which is the (sys_id) ID number to a detail view of that ID number.

I understand this has to do with making a GET request to that api with the specific ID number to get that record. I have created a service for this, which is:

**service.ts**

```
  getIncident(sys_id): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.incidentApiUrl + "/" + sys_id)
       .pipe(
         catchError(this.handleError)
       );
   }
```

**table.component**

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="" *ngFor="let incident of data">
       <td><a href="">{{incident.number}}</a></td>
       <td style="text-overflow: ellipsis;">{{incident.s}}</td>
       <td>{{incident.n}}</td>
       <td>{{incident.u}}</td>
       <td style="text-overflow: ellipsis;">{{incident.sub}}</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

So my question is how do I link the detail view to the first column and populate that view with the details?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a component that taking an ID as parameter would call you api and display the data. 
Using a router you could define the url /incident/:id
And your component to use the "id" in the url and call the api with it's value. So then on your table you just have to define a link to the /incident/:id for each row.

Router :

```
  { path: 'incident/:id', component: IncidentComponent},
```

IncidentComponent :

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from 'app/services/api.service';

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-incident',
  templateUrl: './incident.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./incident.component.scss']
})
export class IncidentComponent {

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  private sub: any;
  idParam: string = "";
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.idParam = params['id'];
      //make you api call here
    });
  }
```